# Difference between returning a value from a function and intialising the value before returning it to the function

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am new to programming and Javascript, and I am trying to understand the difference (if any) in the following code snippets:

**Snippet 1:**

```
try {
  var subjects = mbox.param('subjects');
  return subjects;
} catch(err) {
  return '';
}
```

**Snippet 2:**

```
try {
  var subjects = mbox.param('subjects');
  return subjects;
} catch(err) {
  var subjects = '';
  return subjects;
}
```

In the first snippet, I am returning a variable "subjects" to the function in the "try" block and returning the empty string in the "Catch" block if the code fails.

Whereas in the second snippet, I am returning the same variable in the "catch" block, but this time I am initialising the variable with an empty string before returning.

The variable "subjects" is stringified array, e.g: "['subject 1', 'subject 2']".

They seem to be the same, but I am seeking some help to find out if there is any difference between these two snippets.

Thanks.

Comment: No difference. The creation or assignment to a variable has no side-effects other than regarding how the variable is referenced later. Second snippet is *weird*.

Answer (score 0):

Actually declaring a variable with var gives it a function scope. here you are using a try block and catch block, I suppose it is inside a function. Even if you redeclare 'subjects' it is referring to the same variable. You can access the same variable after the catch block also. So just try console.log(subjects) after the catch block and you will the difference between the two code snippets.
That is why it is highly recommended to utilize const / let, which are block scoped and redeclaration of which is not allowed.

Other than that, returning the empty value directly is better than unnecessarily utilizing a variable additional memory and returning it.

hope it helps !!